# What does the precessional parameter measure?

Tags: climate, paleoclimatology, milankovitch-cycles, orbit

I am wondering what is measured in the plots of change of precession, e.g. when describing Milankovitch Cycles. The values typically vary between .06 and −.06. I am also wondering about what the different values for extreme points mean, but that will probably be answered with the first question.

Comment: Have you used google to search for more information? http://www.eoearth.org/view/article/154612/ may be helpful

Answer (score 3):

What is usually shown in cyclic plots showing precession is the *precession index* ($e \cdot \sin\varpi$ where $e$ is the eccentricity and $\varpi$ is the moving [longitude of the perihelion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude_of_the_periapsis)). It is dimensionless ($e$ and $\sin \varpi$ being ratios).

Here is the precession index for the last 2 Myrs that I plotted using [data](http://vo.imcce.fr/insola/earth/online/earth/La2004/INSOLN.LA2004.BTL.100.ASC) from [Laskar et al. (2004)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1051/0004-6361:20041335) (in the data file, first column is the age, second the eccentricty, third the obliquity and fourth the longitude of perihelion from moving equinox):
[image: Precession cycles]

As for the range of values, by definition a $\sin$ can only take values on the range [-1,1], while the eccentricity (at least during the last 100Myrs) has values ranging from 0 to 0.067; hence a resulting precession index ranging in theory from -0.067 to 0.067.

---

**References**

Laskar, J., Robutel, P., Joutel, F., Gastineau, M., Correia, A. C. M., & Levrard, B. (2004). A long-term numerical solution for the insolation quantities of the Earth. *Astronomy & Astrophysics*, *428*(1), 261–285.